# Getting response after executing entire code

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, dio

I am trying to get some information from a database which I do get eventually, but my if conditions are checked first before getting the data and prints the data after completing the checking of the if conditions, even though I have used await to wait for the data to arrive and then continue.

```
Future reg() async {
    getData().then((value) async {
      print(value["serverIP"]);
      print(value["port"]);
      print(value["passwordMain"]);
      Dio dio = Dio();
      Response response = await dio.get(
          'http://${value["serverIP"]}:${value["port"]}/${value["passwordMain"]}/reg/${controllerEmail.text}/${controllerPassword.text}/${controllerUsername.text}');
      print(response.data);
      return response;
    });
  
ElevatedButton(

      onPressed: () async {
        if (!controllerEmail.text.endsWith("@gmail.com") &
            !controllerEmail.text.endsWith("@gmail.com ") &
            !controllerEmail.text.endsWith("@email.com") &
            !controllerEmail.text.endsWith("@email.com ") &
            !controllerEmail.text.endsWith("@hotmail.com") &
            !controllerEmail.text.endsWith("@hotmail.com ")) {
          if (controllerEmail.text.endsWith(" ")) {
            controllerEmail.text =
                controllerEmail.text.replaceAll(" ", "");
          }
          showErrorDialog(context, 'Unknown Email Address',
              'Try Changing the Email to one of the Providers we Support.');
        } else if ((controllerPassword.text !=
                controllerRePassword.text) |
            controllerPassword.text.isEmpty) {
          showErrorDialog(context, 'Passwords Do not Match/Empty',
              'Please Re-Type your Passwords as they do not Match, or are Empty');
        } else {
          var response = await reg();
          if (response != null) {
            if (response.data == "done") {
              showErrorDialog(context, "Done",
                  "Your Account has been Created, please Log in");
            } else if (response.data == "key") {
              showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  "Incorrect API Key/Main Server Password",
                  "The API Key (Main Server Password) is Incorrect. Kindly, Ensure the Key.");
            } else if (response.data == "email") {
              showErrorDialog(context, "Account Already Exists",
                  "An Account already exists with this Email");
            } else if (response.data == "username") {
              showErrorDialog(context, "Account Already Exists",
                  "An Account already exists with this Username");
            }
          }
        }
      },
      child: const Text("Sign Up"),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `return` in your `reg()` function. Add one before your `getData()` call like this:

```
Future reg() async {
    try {
        return getData().then((value) async {
            Dio dio = Dio();
            Response response = await dio.get(
            'http://${value["serverIP"]}:${value["port"]}/${value["passwordMain"]}/reg/${controllerEmail.text}/${controllerPassword.text}/${controllerUsername.text}');
            return response;
        });
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

Now the function should be properly awaited because it is now returning a promise instead of nothing.

Alternatively, you might prefer to rewrite it using more async/await for easier comprehension, like this:

```
Future reg() async {
    try {
        const value = await getData();
        Dio dio = Dio();
        Response response = await dio.get(
        'http://${value["serverIP"]}:${value["port"]}/${value["passwordMain"]}/reg/${controllerEmail.text}/${controllerPassword.text}/${controllerUsername.text}');
        return response;
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74238420/13909069